# Get cell value from R Dataframe using rpy2

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, rpy2

I have a dataframe like this.

```
            OE000379   OE000373  OE000380   OE000394   OE000399   OE000415
OE000394 0.01562500 0.04687500 0.04687500 0.01562500 0.03320312 0.17382812
OE000399 0.00781250 0.03906250 0.03906250 0.00781250 0.03125000 0.25000000
OE000415 0.01562500 0.07812500 0.07812500 0.01562500 0.06250000 0.06250000
OE000388 0.00390625 0.03515625 0.03515625 0.00390625 0.10937500 0.09375000
```

Using `rpy2` I would like to get a specific cells data. How would I do this?

e.g. OE000379 + OE000394 = 0.01562500

I've managed to be able to do it using the row and column number like this:

```
print(dataframe.rx(1,1))
```

but I'd like to be able to specify the row and column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.rx()` as well.

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as ro
>>> m = ro.r('matrix(1:6, ncol=2, dimnames=list(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:2]))')
>>> print(m)                                                               
  A B
a 1 4
b 2 5
c 3 6
>>> m.rx('b', 'A')                                                         
R object with classes: ('RTYPES.INTSXP',) mapped to:
[2]
>>> m.rx('b', True)                                                        
R object with classes: ('RTYPES.INTSXP',) mapped to:
[2, 5]
```

Comment: thank you so much. in truth, i did try that before but i didn't realise i was converting it to json on the line above. doh! anyway, thank you and marked as answer!